# How to read words instead of characters?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to read a bunch of words from a .txt document and can only manage to read the characters and display them yet. I'd like to do the same but with whole words.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream infile("banned.txt");
if (!infile)

{

    cout << "ERROR: ";
    cout << "Can't open input file\n";

 }

 infile >> noskipws;
 while (!infile.eof())
 {
    char ch;
    infile >> ch;

    // Useful to check that the read isn't the end of file
    // - this stops an extra character being output at the end of the loop
    if (!infile.eof())
    {
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
 }
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Change `char ch;` to `std::string word;` and `infile >> ch;` to `infile >> word;` Done.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @CompuChip Exactly...

Comment: I've tried this before, but I just receive a blank page with nothing showing..

Comment: You also have to put `infile >> word` in `if` instead of `!infile.eof()`, otherwise it'll read just one word.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than mentioned in the previous comments.  You need to define yourself what you definition of words is and how strict you want to be about it.  Obviously for this example, remove the noskipws and make the read statement the loop condition (as already mentioned on many other questions).  Try it and post a new question on what is not working in your case, together with input, output and expected output.

Comment: How are your words separated? Just whitespace or also `.`, `,` or even `:`? What about numbers? You have to tokenize the input string to get actual words.

Comment: You cannot read "words" without defining first what a word is, because there's no one single definition everyone agrees upon.

Answer (score 2):

Change `char ch;` to `std::string word;` and `infile >> ch;` to `infile >> word;` and you're done. Or even better do the loop like this:

```
std::string word;
while (infile >> word)
{
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've managed to do it thanks to the above comments, also had to remove:  infile >> noskipws;